# Need Batch command getting mac address and compare on a txt file?

Tags: batch-file

How to get pc mac address and restart PC if mac is not on the list.txt?, i only have this getting mac command,

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /v /fo csv | findstr Ethernet"') do set MAC=%%a 
echo MAC address of this computer is %MAC%
```

Comment: So you already know how to get the MAC address. There are many questions already here about how to loop through lines in a text file in a batch file, and many questions here about comparing strings in a batch file. Did you spend any time searching?

Comment: You are using the `FINDSTR` command already.  I bet if you read the help file you would find a solution.

Comment: sorry sir i am just a beginner, im trying now to find the variable mac to compare on a maclist.txt and execute something if found. And yes sir i am still searching thank you for the tips.

Comment: for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /v /fo csv | findstr Ethernet"') do set MAC=%%a 
find %MAC% "maclist.txt" && (start image.vbs) || (goto A)

this is what i have compile now and it works somehow, thank you again Mr. Ken White and Mr Squashman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You use `getmac` and pipe the result through `findstr` to filter on the required network adaptor.

   - You store the result into a variable `ThisPCMAC`
2. You use the `type` command to get the content of the `list.txt` file piped through `findstr` to filter on `ThisPCMAC`.

   - You store the result into a variable `FoundMAC`.
3. If `FoundMAC` is defined you `goto :norestart`
4. If `FoundMAC` is not defined you `goto :restart`
5. In `:restart`, you call `shutdown /r` with the required additional params
6. If mistaken, you can call `shutdown /a` in the allotted time (10 minutes here, see `/t 600`).
7. For further help, see `shutdown /?`

The 2 files should be in the same directory.
Example content of `list.txt`:

> ```
> FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FA
> FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FB
> FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FC
> ```

Content of `RestartIfThisPCMACnotInList.bat`:

> ```
> @echo off
>
> set ScriptPath=%~dp0
> set ThisPCMAC=
> set FoundMAC=
>
> echo.
> echo ScriptPath = %ScriptPath%
>
>
> for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /v /fo csv | findstr Ethernet"') do set ThisPCMAC=%%a
> echo.
> echo MAC address of this computer is %ThisPCMAC%
>
> for /F "usebackq delims==" %%b in (`"type %ScriptPath%list.txt | findstr %ThisPCMAC%"`) do set FoundMAC=%%b
>
> if DEFINED FoundMAC (
>    goto :norestart
> ) else (
>    goto :restart
> )
>
>
> :norestart
> echo.
> echo Found %FoundMAC% in %ScriptPath%list.txt: Nothing to do.
> goto :end
>
>
> :restart
> echo.
> echo %ThisPCMAC% not found in %ScriptPath%list.txt: Restarting...
> echo.
> echo shutdown /r /f /t 600 /d p:00:00
> shutdown /r /f /t 600 /d p:00:00
> echo.
> echo Cancel restart with the following command:
> echo    shutdown /a
> goto :end
>
>
> :end
> echo.
> echo %~fp0 ended.
> pause
> ```

Example output for `:norestart`:

> ```
> C:\test\>RestartIfThisPCMACnotInList.bat
>
> ScriptPath = C:\test\
>
> MAC address of this computer is "FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FA"
>
> Found FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FA in C:\test\list.txt: Nothing to do.
>
> C:\test\RestartIfThisPCMACnotInList.bat ended.
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Example output for `:restart`:

> ```
> C:\test\>RestartIfThisPCMACnotInList.bat
>
> ScriptPath = C:\test\
>
> MAC address of this computer is "FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FD"
>
> "FF-AA-BB-CC-DD-FD" not found in C:\test\list.txt: Restarting...
>
> shutdown /r /f /t 600 /d p:00:00
>
> Cancel restart with the following command:
>    shutdown /a
>
> C:\test\RestartIfThisPCMACnotInList.bat ended.
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Comment: Wow this is more detailed than what i simply have. THANK YOU sir

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, you can up vote and/or check as answer ;)